# Problems with psycopg2 timestamp with time zone and inserting selected data from one database to another

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, timestamp-with-timezone

The first problem, I use psycopg2 library in Python to connect to one database and execute this query.

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=**** user=**** password=**** host=**** port=****")
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT datname, age(datfrozenxid), current_setting('autovacuum_freeze_max_age'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM pg_database ORDER BY 2 DESC;")
f = cur.fetchone()
print(f)
```

It returns result like this.

```
('db_name', 186336925, '200000000', datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 6, 15, 12, 46, 233934, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=420, name=None)))
```

I want it to return timestamp results with time zone just like I query in PostgreSQL. How can I do?

And the second problem, I want to insert results of the query above that I define to 'f' variable to my localhost database

```
    conn1 = psycopg2.connect("dbname=**** user=**** password=**** host=localhost port=5432")

with conn1:

    cur1 = conn1.cursor()

    cur1.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS monitor")
    cur1.execute("CREATE TABLE table(datname NAME, age XID, current_setting TEXT, datetime TIMESTAMP)")
    query = "INSERT INTO table (datname, age, current_setting, datetime) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
    cur1.executemany(query, f)

    conn1.commit()
```

But it returns

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

How can I fix it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `INSERT INTO table (...` **-->>** `INSERT INTO monitor (...`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change timestamp inside the query :

```
cur.execute("SELECT datname, age(datfrozenxid), current_setting('autovacuum_freeze_max_age'), to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  as t FROM pg_database ORDER BY 2 DESC;")
```

or you can try to use "datetime" module , check output if it datetime and after that apply format to this value :

```
import psycopg2
import datetime

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=****user=*****password=***** host=****port=****")
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT datname, age(datfrozenxid), current_setting('autovacuum_freeze_max_age'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  FROM pg_database ORDER BY 2 DESC;")
f = cur.fetchone()
for row in f:
    if isinstance(row, datetime.datetime):
        print(row.strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S"))
    else:
        print(row)
```

You also can check documentation using the following link : https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html